# D3.js IE9 error on checking nodes in graphdata

Tags: d3.js

I am having a problem fixing this error. May be someone can explain what is going on here:
I am getting JSON back from server:

```
 d3.json(fullpath, function (json)
        {
            graphData = json;
            if (graphData.nodes.length == 0)
            {
                $.jnotify("Sorry there is no data for graph. Please include social media type in search.");
            }
            drawGraph();
        });
```

here is part of the json:

```
"nodes": [{
        "id": 1,
        "userID": 1,
        "profile_image_url": "images/twitterimage_1.jpg",
        "description": "user1 desc",
        "name": "user 1",
        "location": "Berlin",
        "statuses_count": 5,
        "followers_count": 1
    }
    ,
    {
        "id": 2,
        "userID": 2,
        "profile_image_url": "images/twitterimage_2.png",
        "description": "user2343434 desc",
        "name": "user 2",
        "location": "Berlin",
        "statuses_count": 6,
        "followers_count": 2        
    }
```

then on this line: 'if (graphData.nodes.length == 0)' I do have this error:
'Error: Unable to get value of the property 'nodes': object is null or undefined'

And this is only in IE, not a problem in Chrome or Firefox.

Please help!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. the problem was in this line:
d3.json(fullpath, function (json)

Do you know that IE does json asynchronously be DEFAULT?
and Chrome/Firefox does this call synchronously?

So, the work around is to switch to .ajax call from jquery library:

$.ajax({
            url: dataPath,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: null,
            success: function (response)
            {
            }

thanks!